# How to create an index for a text file?

Tags: text-files

Can anyone point me to a good resource on how to build an index for a large text file?

I am using an OLE Driver on Windows to execute SQL queries against the text file and I don't want to have it read through the entire file.

I've tried googling the topic but I can't find a good resource.

Thank you!

Comment: Use an actual database.

Comment: then don't use a text file. just because you can access it via odbc doesn't mean it's suddenly/magically a database.

Comment: Maybe something like [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)?

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/ could be the solution

Comment: @SLaks - I would love to but this is on a corporate machine and it is an act of congress to get anything besides Microsoft Access installed. But I can't use Access because data exceeds the 2GB limit. And yes, I coud split the database but I am concerned with query speed and the impact on the database schema.

Comment: @MarB - see response to SLaks, I wish it was that simple.

Comment: @Mike -  Thanks for the suggestion. I think SQLLite would be a good solution but see my comment above about downloading/getting applications installed on corporate machines.

Comment: @Andrei - Thank you for this suggestion but I'll run into the same issue I would with getting it installed on corporate machines.

Comment: @UberNubIsTrue - I think RavenDB is just a DLL you reference in your program.  Everything is hosted in proc, there's no need to *install* any new software.  It's basically a library.  I believe this is the case with SQLLite and Lucene.NET as well.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - thanks, maybe I need to investigate those a little more. To give you a little more detail, this is an interim solution that is being implemented on client side machines (no server). I think I would need a C compiler and .NET SDK on each of those machines for this to work (please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: @UberNubIsTrue - I think as long as the .NET Runtime is installed on your machine, you'll be good to go.  It comes with every version of Windows since I think XP or so..

Comment: @MikeChristensen - Thanks Mike. I will look into this more and post back with my final solution, one way or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this post looking for a resource on how to index a text file, I found a great tutuorial at:

[Indexing Random Access Files in Visual Basic](http://trixar.com/~makai/minidb2.htm#create)

Hat-tip to Rick Meyer for writing a clear and educational article on the subject.

Originally, my plan was to use an OLE driver to execute SQL queries on text files. After reading Rick's article above along with this tutorial: [Open for Random in Visual Basic](http://trixar.com/~makai/minidb1.htm), I decided to abandon the SQL approach and perform binary searches on random access files instead.

Choosing Random Access instead of a SQL solution (like the ones suggested in the comments above) is certainly more involved, however, I am very happy with the speed and lightweight nature of the Random Access based application.